# How to write output from api result into a file

Tags: python

I just started to teach myself how to code python and i have a question on how to write output from  API to a file. Below code is i am using  when retrieving data from API and print on screen

```
import requests
url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/"
r = requests.get(url).json()
star_wars = r

print("Name".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['name'],sep = ':')
print ("Height".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['height'],sep = ':')
print ("Gender".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['gender'],sep = ':')
print ("Birthday".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['birth_year'],sep = ':')
```

**expected output**

```
Name      :C-3PO
Height    :167
Gender    :n/a
Birthday  :112BBY
```

How do i write it to file? I tried code below but getting

> Syntax Error: invalid syntax

I am new to the language not sure how to correctly code and achieve the same as above mention output but write to file instead just print.

**my code**

```
with open("star_wars.txt", "a") as f:   
    info1 =("Name".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['name'],sep = ':')
    info2 ="Name".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['name'],sep = ':')
    info3 =("Height".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['height'],sep = ':')
    info4 =("Gender".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['gender'],sep = ':')
    info5 =("Birthday".ljust(10),star_wars['results'][1]['birth_year'],sep = ':')
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info1)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info2)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info3)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info4)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info5)
```

Comment: You could use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) to make your print statements output to the file, that way you wouldn't have to worry about doing it differently. The [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function also accepts an optional keyword argument `file=` to direct where its output goes — the default destination being `stdout`.

Comment: thank you , i will explore this functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gotten most of the way there. There is one small issue, the `sep` argument is a part of the `print` function and you cannot directly use it when writing to the file. But what you can do is rephrase your write statement to do the same thing that the `sep` argument does. Your code should then look like this -

```
with open("star_wars.txt", "a") as f:   
    info1 ="Name".ljust(10)+ ':' + star_wars['results'][1]['name']
    info2 ="Height".ljust(10) + ':' + star_wars['results'][1]['height']
    info3 ="Gender".ljust(10) + ':' + star_wars['results'][1]['gender']
    info4 ="Birthday".ljust(10) + ':' + star_wars['results'][1]['birth_year']
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info1)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info2)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info3)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(info4)
```

Since all the `sep` argument does is separate the listed strings with whatever you pass it, and we only have two other strings being passed to it we can manually add the separator string between them using string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in a comment, this would be very easy using the [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) function since it would allow you to reuse the same calls to the `print()` function you already have. Here's how to do that:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import requests

url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/"
r = requests.get(url).json()
star_wars = r
dest_filepath = 'star_wars.txt'

with open(dest_filepath, 'w') as outp:
    with redirect_stdout(outp) as dest:
        print("Name".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['name'], sep = ':')
        print("Height".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['height'], sep = ':')
        print("Gender".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['gender'], sep = ':')
        print("Birthday".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['birth_year'], sep = ':')

print('-fini-')  # Not redirected.
```

While that's all well and good, but using `redirect_stdout()` can be inconvenient if you want to switch back-and-forth between displaying the output on the screen and send it to a file — such as when you're working on getting the `print` formatting exactly the way you want it.

**Advanced technique**

To make diverting from one destination to the other easier, you can use the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) **decorator** to simplify writing your own *custom* `stdout` redirector that also does the right thing when you're *not* redirecting to a file.

Here's what I mean:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import requests
import sys

TESTING = True  # Suppresses redirection.
dest_filepath = 'star_wars.txt'
url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/"
r = requests.get(url).json()
star_wars = r

@contextmanager
def redirect_output(target):
    if isinstance(target, str):  # File path?
        saved_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open(target, 'w')
    try:
        yield sys.stdout
    finally:
        if isinstance(target, str):
            sys.stdout.close()
            sys.stdout = saved_stdout

target = sys.stdout if TESTING else dest_filepath  # Select where output goes.
with redirect_output(target) as dest:
    print("Name".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['name'], sep = ':')
    print("Height".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['height'], sep = ':')
    print("Gender".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['gender'], sep = ':')
    print("Birthday".ljust(10), star_wars['results'][1]['birth_year'], sep = ':')

print('-fini-')  # Not redirected.
```

Comment: Thanks , some advance stuff for me..i will take a look